# How can you graphically represent the number of authors per page in MediaWiki?

Tags: graph, mediawiki, wiki

We have a MediaWiki wiki. I'd like to be able to report how much collaboration is going on and I thought of the following graph: number of authors per page. So the data would be like this:

```
#Pages #Authors
20     1
10     2
25     3
```

etc. This would show that 20 pages have only 1 author, 10 have 2, 25 have 3, ...

Does anyone know of a way of getting this information?

This information would also somehow need to be shown over time - so if anyone has information on how to do this I'd be grateful. (E.g. last months 25% of pages had 2 or more authors, this month it is 30%).

Comment: Where's my second tumbleweed?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not exactly what you wanted, but it might be a good start. It's a simple special page whose only purpose is to display page names and number of authors.

```
$wgAutoloadClasses['SpecialPagesAuthors'] = $IP . '/additions.php';
$wgSpecialPages['PagesAuthors'] = 'SpecialPagesAuthors';

class SpecialPagesAuthors extends SpecialPage {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( 'PagesAuthors' );
    }
```

This is basically just registering the page.

```
    function execute( $par ) {
        global $wgOut;

        $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );

        $output = <<<WIKITEXT
{| class="wikitable"
! Page !! Authors

WIKITEXT;
```

We put everything in a nice table.

```
        $query_result = $dbr->select(
            array( 'revision', 'page' ),
            array( 'rev_page', 'page_id', 'page_namespace', 'page_title',
                'COUNT(DISTINCT(rev_user_text)) AS unique_authors' ),
            null,
            __METHOD__,
            array( 'GROUP BY' => 'rev_page', 'ORDER BY' => 'unique_authors DESC' ),
            array( 'page' => array( 'LEFT JOIN', 'page_id=rev_page' ) )
        );
```

Here we query the database for pages and number of authors (which is essentially the number of unique user names and IPs who edited the page).

```
        foreach( $query_result as $row ) {
            $title = Title::newFromRow( $row );
            $page_title = $title->getPrefixedText();
            $output .= <<<WIKITEXT
|-
| {$page_title} || {$row->unique_authors}

WIKITEXT;
        }

        $dbr->freeResult( $query_result );
```

Here we output the page name and number of authors to the table and free the DB query result.

```
        $output .= "|}";

        $this->setHeaders();
        $wgOut->addWikiText( $output );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matej: I have made some changes to the code and put it here: http://pastebin.com/KYca9JSV Thanks very much for your help. BTW any idea why the page title is &lt;pagesauthors&gt; ? Otherwise I will create a new SO question.

Comment: It indicates that it's looking for the `pagesauthors` message to use for the page title. Just create a page called `pagesauthors` in the MediaWiki namespace with the desired title. For more info see the [localization documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localization).